# What is the maximum transaction timeout in JBoss 5.1

Tags: transactions, timeout, jboss5.x

I'm noticing peculiarities when attempting to set the transaction timeout to 90000 in JBoss 5.1, specifically in setting transactionTimeout in transaction-jboss-beans.xml:

`<property name="transactionTimeout">90000</property>`

This throws up a variety of errors that are not seen when setting the value to 10800.

I can't seem to find this property documented well anywhere and would like to know if 90000 is too high and if so, what the maximum value is.

Comment: it might help if you post some of those errors.

Comment: I am also interested in any answer about that. It seems hard/impossible to find any official limit, or a way to disable the timeout (what can sounds odd but needed in specific situation). I also faced some weird behavior of JBoss with very high value (unable to boot the server with no error, stuck daemon when running stuff, etc.). I am on JBoss v5.0 by the way.